# Why do muscle spindles send impulses at a constant rate when the muscle is at rest?

Tags: muscles, peripheral-nervous-system

According to my book, the sensory neuron around the muscle spindle is sending impulses at a constant rate, while the entire muscle itself is relaxated (at rest).

So when the muscle stretches the impulse frequency gets higher, right?

According to the book, the reason why this 'constant rate frequency at rest' is happening is because otherwise the muscle spindle wouldn't been able to know the difference between a relaxed and contracted muscle.

I don't understand this reasoning, could anyone explain?